# Loading images using collection view and data is not displaying properly until refreshed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, collectionview

I'm creating an instagram clone and I'm having a small issue. When the profile page loads, i use a collection view to display all of the images of the posts the user has made, and sort these images by date.

When initially loading, what often happens is that the images will appear out of order. However when i refresh the page, the images display correctly. So when loading instead of getting images (4,3,2,1) I'll get something like (1, 3, 2, 1) then refresh and get the correct order.

When i don't use the sort command, the images always display in the correct order, but i need the newest ones to show up first.

Below is the function i use to observe my post data from Firebase, and append them to the posts array. I use an image cache to load my data.

```
let posts = [Post]()

func observePosts() {

    let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-posts").child(currentUser!)

    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postId = snapshot.key

        let postRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(postId)

        postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let postDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                let post = Post(postKey: postId, postData: postDict)
                self.posts.append(post)
                self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
                    return post1.createdAt! > post2.createdAt!
                })
            }
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })
    })

}
```

Loading images using cache:

```
let imageCache: NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = NSCache()
extension UIImageView {

    func loadImagesUsingCacheWith(urlString: String) {

        self.image = nil

        //check cache for image first
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        } else {
            let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: urlString)
            ref.data(withMaxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    //Handle error
                } else {
                    if let img = UIImage(data: data!) {
                        self.image = img
                        imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

cellForItemAt Function:

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell

    let post = posts[indexPath.item]
    cell.configureCell(post: post)

    return cell
}
```

Configure Cell function

```
func configureCell(post: Post) {
    if let imgUrl = post.imgUrl {
        cellImage.loadImagesUsingCacheWith(urlString: imgUrl)
    }
```

### }

UPDATE:

Something super weird happens. In the "cellForItemAt" function, i printed some data from the posts after i declare "let post = posts[indexPath.item]" and the info from the first post always prints to the console twice, while the rest of the data from the posts only prints once. Oddly enough, the picture that is always duplicated when loading the posts is always from the first picture. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: This is just a guess, but did you assure that `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` is called from the main thread?

Comment: @JoRa, if it were called from a background thread, I think it would raise an exception.

Comment: i call reloadData() within the completion block of the data pull for the posts from the server. the weird part is that when i don't sort the array, everything loads properly, but when i sort it i get the issue of the images not displaying correctly.